# How to fix images in visual composer don't expaned layout

Tags: html, image, overflow

I create an element but textarea_html container image overflowed. Help me fix error.
[Image overflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX1sh.png)

```
code param teaxtarea_html
        array(
                'type'          => 'textarea_html',
                'holder'        =>  'div',
                'heading'       => __( 'Text', 'japan-language' ),
                'param_name'    => 'content',
                'value'         => __( 'Default value', 'japan-language' ),
                'description'   => __( 'Box Text', 'japan-language' ),
                'admin_label'   => false,
                'weight'        => 0,
                'group'         => 'Custom Group',
            )
```

Comment: post some code. help us to help you

Comment: code param teaxtarea_html
 array(
                    'type'          => 'textarea_html',
                    'holder'        =>  'div',
                    'heading'       => __( 'Text', 'japan-language' ),
                    'param_name'    => 'content',
                    'value'         => __( 'Default value', 'japan-language' ),
                    'description'   => __( 'Box Text', 'japan-language' ),
                    'admin_label'   => false,
                    'weight'        => 0,
                    'group'         => 'Custom Group',
                )

Comment: why not should check the styles of the dom?